# Maintain development and live site on appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, deployment

I am trying to set up a development/testing site for my app engine web app.  I would like to be able to push features to the development site, then once they are tested update my live/user facing site.

- What tools are available to manage these sorts of updates?
- Are there any that integrate with the Google deploy plugin for eclipse?
- Are there any good places to learn about these types of systems?
- What keywords should I be Googling for so I can learn more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create at least two application let's name it (do not use version since you could corrupt production):
yourname.appspot.com (prodution)
yournametest.appspot.com (test)

Copy data from production to test with datastore admin (need to add appengine_config.py with producton name - see documentation in appengine_config.py to allow migration of data).

Change version name in app.yaml before tests to allow rollback to previous version.

Deploy test - current app version to current - do tests see logs and results:
appcfg update -A yournametest yoursourcedir

After test success. Backup production if there is any risk of data corruption. Deploy production - check if new version working - change default version to current.
appcfg update -A yourname yoursourcedir

The best place to learn is Google App Engine page and Google.

There is some plugins but it slow better use scripts or command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple versions of your app; these can serve in parallel so you can test a new version before making it live. All versions will use the same datastore.

If you want to use different apps for development and production, you can do that too. There's not really any special integration required for this, and I'm not aware of any tools to facilitate it, since it's such a simple task. If you're using the command line tools, you can pass `--application` to override the app ID in `app.yaml`; this isn't available in Eclipse to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers from @Nick and @Chameleon are great workable solutions. I use both methods, depending on the scenario.

For minor upgrades, @Nick solution makes sense. You can test the new version live by appending the version number before the app (eg: `3.app-id.appspot.com`). You also need to make sure that new page doesn't use the default (previous) URL.

For major releases that may affect the user and/or data, use @Chameleon solution (GAE has a tool to copy your data over to yr test app under `Datastore Admin`). Sometimes the app behaves well in local dev but breaks on live deployment.